# Solution works properly for small array size but fails for a bigger array

Tags: python-3.x

Problem statement:There are 2 players Bob and Andy. The game starts with an array of distinct integers and the rules are as follows:

Bob always plays first and the two players move in alternating turns.
In a single move, a player chooses the maximum element currently present in the array and removes it as well as all the other elements to its right.
The modifications made to the array during each turn are permanent, so the next player continues the game with the remaining array. The first player who is unable to make a move loses the game.Andy and Bob play  games. Given the initial array for each game, find and print the name of the winner on a new line. If Andy wins, print ANDY; if Bob wins, print BOB.

This solution correctly predicts the winner if the array size is small but for a larger size array it returns a run time error.[Example of test case where code fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J16S2.png).In the image the first line is the number of games and the second line is the array size.

```
enter code here
#!/bin/python3
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def findmax(array):
    max = array[0]
    posof = 0
    for i in range(0,len(array)):
        if array[i]>max:
            max = array[i]
            posof = i   
    return posof

def gamingArray(arr,no_of_games):
    # Write your code here
    count = 0
    while (no_of_games!=0):
        while(arr.__len__()!=0):
            pos = findmax(arr)
            print(pos)
            arr = arr[0:pos]
            print(arr)
            count = count+1
        no_of_games = no_of_games-1
    if(count%2==0):
        return 'ANDY'
    else:
        return 'BOB' 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    g = int(input().strip())

    for g_itr in range(g):
        arr_count = int(input().strip())
        arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
        result = gamingArray(arr,g)
        fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What does your code output?  What do you want it to output?  What does "works fine" and "fails" mean here?

Comment: Would you also describe the actual problem to be solved, at least briefly? What if hackerrank goes south, your question should still be legible.

Comment: *"for a larger size array it returns a run time error."* What size, and what runtime error? Be specific, write a [mcve].

Comment: The question as to what run time error. I don't know.The hacker rank compiler doesn't specify.